# How do I set JAVA environment variables system wide?

Tags: environment-variables

I work as java/j2ee application developer so kindly tell me how to set JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME, CLASSPATH so that I may use Tomcat, Mysql ,java all together in Terminal.

I may be using all together in a pure CLI server environment, or in a GUI desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

Using 12.04, placing the information in `/etc/environment` worked for me:

```
tku@buster:~$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
[...]
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
JAVA_HOME=/home/tku/work/jdk1.7.0_05
```

Answer (score 1):

***You wanna make sure your Java is the default:***

**Set Default Java Version**

Use the alternatives command to set the default java version.

```
~ ~↓↓$↓↓ sudo alternatives --config java
```

Select Java:

If your system has multiple Java versions, the above command will list all Java versions.

There are 3 programs which provide 'java'.

```
  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
 + 1           java-11-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.12.0.7-4.fc35.x86_64/bin/java)
   2           java-latest-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.1.0.12-2.rolling.fc35.x86_64/bin/java)
*  3           /usr/java/jdk-17.0.1/bin/java
```

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: whateverisyours

---

***Verify Java Version***

Check the java version using the following command.

```
~ ~↓↓$↓↓ java --version
```

output feks.:

```
java 18.0.2 2022-07-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2+9-61)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2+9-61, mixed mode, sharing)
```

---

***Then, add the required variables.***

To set the environment variables for a particular user, place the below variables in the `.bash_profile` file in the home directory or in the `/etc/environment` file **for system wide settings**.

```
~ ~↓↓$↓↓ sudo nano /etc/environment
```

and your information there is current version of Java:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk-18.0.2/bin/
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-18.0.2/
```

if your using `JRE` then it will look something like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jre*****/bin/
export JAVA_HOME:/usr/java/jre*****/
```

---

***Test it by executing:***

```
~ ~↓↓$↓↓ echo $JAVA_HOME
~ ~↓↓$↓↓ echo $PATH
~ ~↓↓$↓↓ java --version
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of Java (or, for that matter, multiple versions of anything) installed, and want to be able to switch between them, [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) is worth considering. It enables you to load, unload, and switch between the environment setups for different installed versions of any software that it's configured to handle. It's a *de facto* standard on clusters and, although it's a bit of a pain to set up at first, it's well worth the effort, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Add the path to the "bin" directory inside the java directory after the colon.

```
PATH = "blah/blah/blah:........../xyz/yvc:/YOUR/PATH/TO/JAVA/BIN"
```

Save it. Now run the following command...

```
source /etc/environment
```

Check whether it is properly installed.

```
java -version
```