# changing /etc/environment did not affect my environment variables

Tags: environment-variables

I'm trying to install Euler expert system following [these instructions](http://eulersharp.sourceforge.net/INSTALL). To add the environment variable I edited my `/etc/environment` to become as follows:

```
 PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:
/home/mohammad/Desktop/eye"
 EYE_HOME = "/home/mohammad/Desktop/eye"
```

But when I use `printenv PATH` I don't see the new directory added to my path.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That link isn't working right now (SourceForge is down) but can you specify whether you want system-wide environment variables? Since it's for an application, this is likely the case, and therefore a lot of the answers below are wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know the reason why PATH wasn't changed (after relogin), but

```
EYE_HOME = "/home/mohammad/Desktop/eye"
--------^-^
```

those spaces prevent EYE_HOME to be set.

It should be noted that `/etc/environment` is not a script file, but a kind of assignment file that is read by PAM. OTOH such spaces are not allowed in script files like `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` either.

If you use a script file, you need to export the variables as shown in Avinash Raj's answer.

Please note that while `~/.bashrc` works if you start your program from a terminal window, it may not work if you start it from the graphical environment, since it's not sourced by the display manager.

Comment: @gunnar-hijalmarsson --- correct. The fact that the display manager is not started from my shell bite me much times. I have posted a trick to see the variables that are set in the DE: http://askubuntu.com/a/356973/16395

Comment: Nice trick, @Rmano! Any chance that you can add it to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables ?

Comment: Thanks -  I never edited one of that and I do not know if I had the permissions. I will look into it if I have time, but otherwise feel free to copy/paste whatever you want --- that page needs badly to be put up-to-date. One question: do *all* the display managers (lightdm, gdm, kdm) source `~/.profile` even if my default shell is not `bash` but, for example, `zsh`?

Comment: Checked by myself. I use `zsh`; the applications launched by the DE see variables set in `~/.pam_environment` and `~/.profile` (NOT `~/.zprofile`). This is good and bad, but the bad part is solved by changing `.profile` so that it sources my `.zprofile` and `.zshenv`. And I confirm that using `.pam_environment` is bad, it is overwritten sometime (shouldn't, but it is).

Comment: @Rmano: I know that `~/.profile` is sourced by lightdm and gdm; not sure about kdm.

Comment: Thanks! The spaces prevented me from setting it properly

Comment: I have
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/instantclient10_1`
in /etc/environment, but after a reboot, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set when I open a terminal window. Why not?

Comment: @battey: Please ask a new question if you need help with that.

Answer (score 5):

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

After that add the below lines,

```
export EYE_HOME="/home/mohammad/Desktop/eye"
export PATH=$PATH:$EYE_HOME
```

Save the file and sourec it,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: would that be a system wide variable ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/154665/how-do-i-set-java-environment-variables-system-wide

Comment: @AvinashRaj: this variables not only will be user-only, but they will not be seen if the application is not started from a command-line terminal... the graphical environment is started by itself, not using the user's shell. See  http://askubuntu.com/a/356973/16395

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two files too for system wide configuration:

- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/bashrc`

For user wide configuration:

- `$HOME/.profile`
- `$HOME/.bashrc`

Just append the variables as you have done on `/etc/environment`. But you will have to login and logout (or run the proper reload). Maybe by login and logout `/etc/environment` would work but I am not sure.

Answer (score -1):

You want to edit your .bashrc file in your home directory.

When you edit the path you should include `:$PATH` on the end so you don't replace the current path.