# How do I modify /etc/environment?

Tags: environment-variables

I'm new to Ubuntu and I would like to add a new variable to `/etc/environment` as part of an installation (as detailed in the question linked below). I have attempted to modify `environment`  by opening it in a text editor (I'm using MobaXterm with MobaTextEditor). However, when I try to save the modified file, the changes aren't saved (when I open the file again, it's back to the unmodified version). I assume that I'd have to use `sudo` or something similar to open it, but I how do I do this? Or is there another method?

[changing /etc/environment did not affect my environment variables](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391515/changing-etc-environment-did-not-affect-my-environment-variables)